# App rejected because of using global hotkeys

Tags: macos, appstore-approval, global-hotkey

The last days I sent a new build of my app to Apple to fix some minor bugs with macOS Catalina. This evening Apple called me and explained that they are refusing the new version in the AppStore because the application monitors keystrokes. I use the Clipy/Magnet library (github.com/Clipy/Magnet) to manage the hotkeys. This library uses a Carbon API. Admittedly, I'm a little surprised - on the one hand that Apple is calling me directly via phone about this and on the other hand the use of this library has not caused any problems so far. The only thing I noticed about the new build was that Catalina asks for "Input-Monitoring" at the first start of the program. I've installed several other programs that also respond to global hotkeys and none of them require the permission for "input monitoring".
Does anyone have a similar phenomenon under Catalina or how do you solve the problem of query/monitoring global hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

I know of numerous applications using [the MASShortcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut) framework, and I don't believe they've had issues with the store.  It also uses a carbon API, but I think the issue in Magnet is the call to [`CGEvent.tapCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454426-cgeventtapcreate?language=objc#) which can globally monitor *all* keyboard input, and which `MASShortcut` doesn't use.